# Kendo Mobile - Can not refresh listview on ModalView Close

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, refresh, kendo-mobile

I can not refresh the listview when a dialog which add's or deletes rows from this listview is closes.

I tried several things. but the following does not work

```
function closeModalViewRemove() {

        $("#modalview-app-remove").kendoMobileModalView("close");
        //--- this is not working -- start ---
              refreshAppList();
        //--- this is not working -- finish ---

};


function refreshAppList() {
    var applist = $('#applist').data('kendoMobileListView');
    applist.dataSource.read();   
    applist.refresh();
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should do the trick.

```
 $("#applist").data("kendoMobileListView").refresh()
```

Check documentation on refresh for further information: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/listview

Iam not sure why you have used datasource.read(). This function can be used only if you have dynamic data items that are loaded into a template inside the listview and you are deleting items in the source itself and reading rest of the source items after each time you close modal view.Inorder to delete row of a listview and display rest of the rows,just calling refresh function with id of the listview is enough.

Comment: Hi @ShinyJos, actually I also tried this one.. The listview doesn't refresh

Comment: Its tough to say..can u post the code with a fiddle..i'l try to get it to work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6fWr3/4/  I may made a mistake also in fiddle, couldnt get the dialog open there

Comment: I cant edit your code because i cant figure out what it is supposed to do.Please post a working code where i can work with only refreshing your list

Comment: my problem turned to the following problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279095/kendo-ui-datasource-add-function-not-working-properly can you please have a look?