# Kendo Ui DataSource Add Function not working properly

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, addition

I defined a Kendo Data Source as below. It is populating values in a ListView.

```
 var datasourceAppList = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      create: function(options){
        //alert(options.data.desc);
        alert(options.data.desc);
        var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("LsAppList"));
        localData.push(options.data);
        localStorage.setItem("LsAppList", JSON.stringify(localData)); //localStorage["LsAppList"] = JSON.stringify(localData); 
        options.success(localData);
      },
      read: function(options){ 
          var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["LsAppList"]); 
          options.success(localData);
      },
      update: function(options){
        var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["LsAppList"]); 
        for(var i=0; i<localData.length; i++){
          if(localData[i].extappId == options.data.extappId){
            localData[i].desc = options.data.desc;
            localData[i].deviceNo = options.data.deviceNo;
            localData[i].validationKey = options.data.validationKey;
          } 
        }
        localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(localData); 
        options.success(localData);
      },
      destroy: function(options){ 
        var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["LsAppList"]); 
        localData.remove(options.data.ID);
        localStorage["LsAppList"] = JSON.stringify(localData); 
        options.success(localData);
      },
    },
        schema: {
      model: {
        extappId: "ID",
        fields: {
          extappId: { type: "number" },
          desc: { type: "string" },
          deviceNo: { type: "number" },
          validationKey: { type: "string" }
        }}
    },
  });
```

**First :** I call the following code. it adds the data correctly both to te page listview and localStorage.

```
datasourceAppList.add({ extappId: "9905", desc: "test", deviceNo: "5", validationKey: "CACACACA"});

datasourceAppList.sync();
```

**Second:** I call the folowing code

```
datasourceAppList.add({ extappId: "9908", desc: "harvest", deviceNo: "7", validationKey: "ppppppp"});

datasourceAppList.sync();
```

**Problems:**

1. the page is showing the first record twice.
2. The localstorage has 2 times the first record and 1 time the second record.

what am I doing wrong?

--- one problem still exists. though the localStorage is correct, the listview is populating wrong.

First Record Add : ListView is Correct
Second Record Add : ListView is Corract
Third Record Add : First 2 lines shows the first record and the last line shows the last record.

My HTML code is

```
<div id="applications" data-role="view"  data-title="Defined Applications" data-layout="default" data-model="appdetail">
    <ul id="applist" data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-source="datasourceAppList" data-template="tmp" data-click="listViewClick" data-auto-bind="true"></ul>


    <p align="center">
        <a  style="width: 30%" data-role="button" data-rel="modalview" data-click="showModalViewAdd" id="buttonAddApplication" data-icon="ecg-plus">Add</a>
        <a  style="width: 30%" data-role="button" data-rel="modalview" data-click="refreshApplicationList" id="buttonRefreshApplication" data-icon="refresh">Refresh</a>
    </p>

</div>

<script id="tmp" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <a id = "#: extappId #">#: desc # </a>

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually a combined problem:

You `schema` definition is:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        extappId: "ID",
        fields: {
            extappId: { type: "number" },
            desc: { type: "string" },
            deviceNo: { type: "number" },
            validationKey: { type: "string" }
        }
    }
 }
```

It says `extappId: "ID"`... what is this? Do you want to say that `extappId` is the `id` of that record? If so, the actual definition should be:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "extappId",
        fields: {
            extappId: { type: "number" },
            desc: { type: "string" },
            deviceNo: { type: "number" },
            validationKey: { type: "string" }
        }
    }
 }
```

What happens here is not being (correctly) defined the `id`, KendoUI expects that `id` is actually `id` and since this is not being set during the `create` next time that you `sync` it tries to save it, it is equivalent to:

```
datasourceAppList.add({ extappId: 9905, desc: "test", deviceNo: 5, validationKey: "CACACACA"});
datasourceAppList.add({ extappId: 9908, desc: "harvest", deviceNo: 7, validationKey: "ppppppp"});
datasourceAppList.sync();
```

But if you try this, you will see that then `create` is never invoked. Now what happens is that the `id` of the record (i.e. `extappId`) is already defined and not null and so KendoUI believes that is already saved.

For solving this second issue my recommendation is defining the `schema` as:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "ID",
        fields: {
            extappId: { type: "number" },
            desc: { type: "string" },
            deviceNo: { type: "number" },
            validationKey: { type: "string" }
        }
    }
 }
```

Now, the `id` is a field called `ID` and this `ID` should be created on `transport.create` (cannot be set before invoking `add` method).

Then, you set it in `create` and you can use:

```
create: function(options){
    // Set `ID` to kendo.guid
    options.data.ID = kendo.guid();
    alert(options.data.desc);
    var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("LsAppList"));
    localData.push(options.data);
    localStorage.setItem("LsAppList", JSON.stringify(localData)); //localStorage["LsAppList"] = JSON.stringify(localData); 
    options.success(localData);
},
```

Check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/n7sNd/3/

Comment: Dear @OnaBai  I have one other problem connected with this question. I added some more information to my question. Can you please kindly have a look of that also.. With your correction, the localStorage is correct but still I have problem on the listview.. though the localstorage, the page is showing the records wrong unless I refresh the page.